# Reactjs with Pokeapi

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app that searches the name of the pokemon reads the data eg. name, height, weight. Now when it comes to the abilities I can't get the value of the name of the ability.

here's my app.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Request from 'superagent';

class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      body: "",
      value: "",
      name: "",
      abilities: "",
      order: "",
      weight: "",
      height: ""
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value.toLowerCase()});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    var url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+this.state.value;
    Request.get(url).then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        body: response.body,
        height: response.body.height,
        weight: response.body.weight,
        abilities: response.body.abilities,
        name: response.body.name,
        order: response.body.order,
        picFront: response.body.sprites.front_default,
        picBack: response.body.sprites.back_default,
        picShiny: response.body.sprites.front_shiny,


      });
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="flex">
          <div className="App">
          <h1>Search Pokemon</h1>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className="app2">
          <h1><small>{this.state.order} </small>{this.state.name}</h1>
          <img alt={this.state.name} src={this.state.picFront}/>
          <img alt={this.state.name} src={this.state.picBack}/>
          <img alt={this.state.name} src={this.state.picShiny}/>
          <p>Height: {this.state.height}</p>
          <p>Weight: {this.state.weight}</p>
          <p>list of abilities here</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
};


export default App;
```

Comment: what do you have in `this.state.abilities`?

Comment: i was trying to get the values of abilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abilities has this structure. You can check this by logging this.state.abilities

```
abilities: [
  {
    slot: 3,
    is_hidden: true,
    ability: {
      url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/31/",
      name: "lightning-rod"
    }
  },
  {
    slot: 1,
    is_hidden: false,
    ability: {
      url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/9/",
      name: "static"
    }
  }
]
```

It's just an array. What you need to do is iterate over this array to retrieve those name values. There are a lot of ways to do this but the general logic should be something like:

"For each of these objects in the abilities array, I need to retrieve ability.name"

I am going to post some code here but try to solve it yourself before looking at mine.

In your p tag, you can do this

```
    <p>
      list of abilities here: 
      {this.state.abilities && this.state.abilities.map((abilityObject) => 
        abilityObject.ability.name).join(', ')}
    </p>
```

Comment: I got an error says 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined'

Comment: Which pokemon are you requesting?

Comment: i haven't input the name of pokemon.

Comment: My mistake. Check out my edited code. That should make the function run only when there are abilities available.

Comment: can I ask if you know how to handle file handling in React?